# 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable - accessing to views by anonymous and authenticateds users

Tags: python, django, detailsview, django-class-based-views, anonymous-users

I have the following Urls:

The main `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^accounts/profiles/', include('accounts.urls', namespace = 'accounts')),
```

The `accounts/urls.py`

```
url(r"^(?P<email>[\w.@+-]+)/$", views.UserDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

I've created the UserDetailView to view the data of an user

```
User = get_user_model()

class UserDetailView(UserProfileDataMixin, generic.DetailView):

    template_name = 'accounts/user_detail.html'
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(
                    User,
                    email__iexact=self.kwargs.get("email")
                    )

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        user = self.request.user
        following = UserProfile.objects.is_following(self.request.user, self.get_object())
        context['following'] = following
        context['recommended'] = UserProfile.objects.recommended(self.request.user)
        return context
```

When I access to `/accounts/profiles/luisa@gmail.com/` URL when the user who performs the request is loggedIn, the request is O.K

[08/Sep/2017 23:56:20] "GET /accounts/profiles/luisa@gmail.com/ HTTP/1.1" 200 23577

But, I want that this view to be acceded by anonymous users or unauthenticated users, which does not register in my application.
When an anonymous user access to  `/accounts/profiles/luisa@gmail.com/` url I get this message:

```
TypeError: 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable
[09/Sep/2017 00:00:50] "GET /accounts/profiles/luisa@gmail.com/ HTTP/1.1" 500 151513
```

My custom manager method `is_following()` is:

```
def is_following(self, user, followed_by_user):
    user_profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    if created:
        return False
    if followed_by_user in user_profile.following.all():
        return True
    return False
```

and the recommended() method:

```
def recommended(self, user, limit_to=10):
    print(user)
    profile = user.profile
    # my profile

    following = profile.following.all()
    # profile of the people that I follow

    following = profile.get_following()
    # TO avoid recommend myself

    # Exclude the users recommendations which I already follow 
    qs = self.get_queryset().exclude(user__in=following).exclude(id=profile.id).order_by("?")[:limit_to]
    return qs
```

How to can I allow my `UserDetailView` to be accessed by anonymous users?

Comment: While trying to diagnose the problem you create another problem, that has nothing to do with your original problem. Keep debugging statements simple. If you want to understand why `reverse_lazy("accounts:detail", email=email)` with a queryset will never ever work, ask a separate question (hint: a queryset is not an email address).

Comment: The problem is with your two custom manager methods `is_following` and `recommended`. Remove your debugging and replace with the code for those manager methods.

Comment: @Melvyni t's true about of a queryset is not email address, you have reason. In relation to my error, it's true too, puntually, is with the custom manager method `is_following()`   I don't understand much when you tell me  **Remove your debugging and replace with the code for those manager methods** my apologies ...

Comment: I meant, show the code for `is_following()`, then we can better help you. To keep the question clean, best to remove your debugging code. Right now, we can't tell why `is_following()` tries to iterate an `AnonymousUser` object.

Comment: @Melvyn I've add the custom managers methods `is_following()` and `recommended()` Thanks for their orientation.

Answer (score 1):

First create a `LoginRequired` class.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.generic import View
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator


class LoginRequired(View):
    """
    Redirects to login if user is anonymous
    """
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(LoginRequired, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

And **then:**

```
class UserDetailView(LoginRequired,UserProfileDataMixin, generic.DetailView):
```

Comment: But the `LoginRequired` class is to redirects to login if user is anonymous, I want allow to the anonymous users access and view the `UserDetailView`

Comment: But this will act only when, unauthenticated user try to access user profile.

Comment: And logically if one is not authenticated they should be redirected to login if they click on `detail profile`.

Comment: And if someone is not logged in how they can accesss their profile detail??

Comment: I want that a anoymous user have the able of view the user detail profile of the users which if exists in the system. Something similar to when you can access to twitter or facebook profile of somebody without needed of create an account in facebook or twitter.

Comment: Hi Astik. When chatty material is removed from your posts, please do not add it back. Mutual editing is a key part of how Stack Overflow works.